# iDangerous Swiper, thumbnail control

Tags: jquery, html

I’m a beginner coder. Does anybody know how to link thumbnail images to the swiper so that clicking a thumbnail moves the swiper-container to the corresponding slide? Thanks for your help!

Example: http://markdarren.com/F13/test.html

```
    <div class="swiper-container">  
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/jacket2.png"></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/jacket3.png"></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/jacket4.png"></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/jacket5.png"></div>
      </div>
    </div>        
    <div class="thumb">
      <div><a href="" title="onClick goto jacket 2"><img src="images/jacket2.png"></a></div>
      <div><a href="" title="onClick goto jacket 3"><img src="images/jacket3.png"></a></div>
      <div><a href="" title="onClick goto jacket 4"><img src="images/jacket4.png"></a></div>
      <div><a href="" title="onClick goto jacket 5"><img src="images/jacket5.png"></a></div>
    </div>     
    <script src="js/scroller/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scroller/js/idangerous.swiper-2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
    pagination: '.pagination',
    paginationClickable: true
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: What does the documentation for this swiper say?

Comment: http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php My extremely limited coding abilities prevents me from understanding it.

Comment: I don't know when this post has been added, but now if you go to the swiper slider documentation you can easily find your answer there under the "Thumbs" section. Also, please mind that I have tested on 2 versions of swiper-slider: 4.0.5 and 4.5.0 and it works only on the latest version. Hope this helps you or someone else.

EDIT: there are actually 2 ways to do it. One is with custom pagination, and other is with thumbs slider. I personally recommend the Thumbs slider way since it was build specifically for this scenario and provides more utility over the visible thumbs. Good Luck!

Answer (score 9):

Change everything in your script tag to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
        pagination: '.pagination',
        paginationClickable: true
    });

    $(".thumb").on('click', 'div', function(){
        mySwiper.slideTo($(this).index(), 500);
    });
});
```

The bit I've added isn't tested, but should mean that on a click on one of the divs in your .thumbs bit (I'm ignoring your a tags) will swipe to the index of that div (e.g. is it div 1, div 2 etc).

Answer (score 0):

Small correction :) -> it's actually "slideTo" not "swipeTo"

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
        pagination: '.pagination',
        paginationClickable: true
    });

    $(".thumb").on('click', 'div', function(){
        mySwiper.slideTo($(this).index(), 500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small plugin using the Swiper API that enables you to add custom thumbnails and link them to your Swiper instance.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    direction: 'horizontal',
  })

  swiperThumbs(mySwiper, {
    element: 'swiper-thumbnails',
    activeClass: 'is-active'
  });
});
```

**Html:**

```
<div class="swiper-thumbnails">
  <button type="button">any html content</button>
  <button type="button">any html content</button>
  <button type="button">any html content</button>
</div>
```

## Download:

**https://github.com/gijsroge/Swiper-Thumbnails**

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution for this problem

```js
    var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      loop:true,
      loopedSlides: 5, //looped slides should be the same
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
    });
    var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      slidesPerView: 4,
      touchRatio: 0.2,
      loop: true,
      loopedSlides: 5, //looped slides should be the same
      slideToClickedSlide: true,
    });
    galleryTop.controller.control = galleryThumbs;
    galleryThumbs.controller.control = galleryTop;
```

```css
    html, body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      background: #000;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color:#000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
    }
    .gallery-top {
      height: 80%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .gallery-thumbs {
      height: 20%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 10px 0;
    }
    .gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide {
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 0.4;
    }
    .gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide-active {
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.5/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div class="swiper-container gallery-top">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?random)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?random)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?random)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?random)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?random)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?random)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?random)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?random)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?random)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?random)"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Arrows -->
    <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="swiper-container gallery-thumbs">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?random)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?random)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?random)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?random)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?random)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?random)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?random)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?random)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?random)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1200/1200/?random)"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.5/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
```