# Swiper.js calling click() on thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I've been using the swiper.js javascript library to create a slider with vertical thumbnails, where if you click the thumbnail, the main image will "slide" to that image.

[image: Example]

The functionality works perfectly when I manually click on a thumbnail, however, I need to change the main image when the user selects the color swatches as well. I've called the javascript function click() on the thumbnail element, I've tried calling click() on both the img itself and the div containing the img. Unfortunately I'm not seeing the same functionality, my click event does register, and I am able to console log/change the border of the thumbnail, but it doesn't run the swiper.js function "onThumbClick":

There is a function in swiper.js called "onThumbClick" which I've done a console log in, and I've noticed that it is not being called when I use javascript click() but it is being called when I click it manually.

I'm definitely no javascript pro so I'm not exactly sure what's happening here.

**EDIT - adding some code snippets**

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-container gallery-top">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <?php foreach ($gallery as $image): ?>
                <?php if ($this->isGalleryImageVisible($image) and (strpos($image->getLabel(), 'swatch')) === false) : ?>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                        <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
                            <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $image->getFile())->resize($imgWidth, $imgHeight); ?>" data-zoom-image="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $image->getFile()); ?>"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php if (count($gallery) > 0): ?>
        <div class="swiper-container gallery-thumbs">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <?php foreach ($gallery as $image): ?>
                    <?php 
                        $url = $image->getUrl();
                        $endUrl = strrpos($url, '/');
                        $sku = $endUrl === false ? $url : substr($url, $endUrl + 1);
                    ?>
                    <?php if ($this->isGalleryImageVisible($image) and (strpos($image->getLabel(), 'swatch')) === false) : ?>
                        <div class="swiper-slide thumbnails" data-sku="<?php echo $sku?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo $image->getUrl() ?>" data-sku="<?php echo $sku?>"/>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Javascript (Init Slider)

```
<script>
var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
  direction: 'vertical',
  spaceBetween: 10,
  slidesPerView: 6,
  freeMode: true,
  watchSlidesVisibility: false,
  watchSlidesProgress: false,
  speed: 0,
});
var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
  zoom: {
    maxRatio: 5,
  },
  spaceBetween: 10,
  direction: 'horizontal',
  thumbs: {
    swiper: galleryThumbs
  },
  //preventing zoom containers from appearing over inactive swiper images
  on:{slideChange: function() {
    jQuery('.zoomContainer').remove();
  }}
});

jQuery('.swiper-zoom-container').children('img').mouseover(function(){
    jQuery(this).elevateZoom();
});

</script>
```

Calling click on my thumbnail:

```
jQuery(".thumbnails[data-sku='" + sku + "']").click(function(e) {
        console.log('click');
        console.log(jQuery(".thumbnails[data-sku='" + sku + "']"));
        jQuery(".thumbnails[data-sku='" + sku + "']").css('border', '1px solid black');
    });
    jQuery(".thumbnails[data-sku='" + sku + "']").click();
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a dynamic click event? `$(document).on('click', 'JQUERY_SELECTOR', function() { .... });`

Comment: Can you post your HTML and javascript? We'll be able to help more then.

Comment: I've added some in now, I think you will see in my last snippet of code the dynamic click event.

Comment: Found this to be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413572/idangerous-swiper-thumbnail-control/52040404

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for this

Here is my code

```
var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
        spaceBetween: 5,
        freeMode: true,
        watchSlidesVisibility: true,
        watchSlidesProgress: true,
        breakpoints: {
            0: {
                slidesPerView: 3,
            },
            992: {
                slidesPerView: 4,
            },
        }
    });

    var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
        spaceBetween: 10,
        pagination: {
            el: ".swiper-pagination",
            dynamicBullets: true,
        },
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
        thumbs: {
            swiper: galleryThumbs
        },
    });
```

Whenever you select swatch from dropdown

```
    $('select[name=p_option]').on('change',function(){
 
        var indexToMove = $('option:selected', this).attr('data-val');
       
        galleryTop.slideTo(indexToMove,1000,false);
    });`
```

Here is html in my case there are shades in dropdown

```
<select class="form-control" name="p_option">
                                <option>Select Shade</option>
                                <option data-val="0" value="0">0</option>
                                <option data-val="1" value="1">1</option>
                                <option data-val="2" value="2">2</option>
                                <option data-val="3" value="3">3</option>
                                                              </select>
```

**NOTE: Just display images in thumbs in same sequence as in select Dropdown because swiper slideTo function slides images using INDEX**